# use excel 2010 to update variables in batch file

Tags: perl, excel, batch-file, vba

I am trying to update variables using `excel 2010 vba` that are used in a `batch` file that runs a code in `perl`.  Below is the `VBA` that updates each of the variables and the `perl` code without the variables is the code that works. With the variables the batch file opens and closes quickly so the syntax appears to be wrong.  Even when I remove `@echo off` I can not view the error. Thank you :).

**VBA**

```
'Update values and call perl
Dim var1 As String
Dim var2 As String
Dim var3 As String
Dim var4 As String

var1 = MyDirectory
var2 = MyDirectory & "sample_descriptor.txt"
var3 = "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\test_probes8.txt"
var4 = MyDirectory & "output.txt"
Set wshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\spikein.bat"
```

**perl code (no variables)**

```
perl get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\555_7-2-2015" "sample_descriptor.txt" < test_probes8.txt > "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\555_7-2-2015\output.txt"
```

**perl code (with variables)**

```
perl get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl "%var1%" "%var2%" < %var3% > "%var4%"
```

**Batch file**

```
@echo off
perl "C:\cygwin\home\cmccabe\get_imagene_spikein_probe_values.pl" "%var1%" "%var2%" < "%var3" > "%var4%"
```

Comment: Why do you need to use all three languages?

Comment: All that code and you still haven't included the contents of the batch file.

Comment: Since I am on a windows machine I am using a `batch` file to run a `perl` script as it seems easier.  i wrote the initial script in `perl` using ubuntu but most of the users are on a windows platform.  Thank you :).

Comment: @SomethingDark I edited the post to include the batch file.  Thank you :).

Comment: @dan1111 since users are familiar with `excel` it made sense to use `vba` as well. Thank you :).

Comment: Perl exists on Windows, and in fact must be installed on your users' systems in order for your batch script to even work at all. I recommend getting rid of both the VBA and batch options and working exclusively in Perl for this task.

Comment: It's unclear how local variables in a VBA macro (var1, var2, var3, var4) could be visible to the batch file without being added as parameters to wshell.Run

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because it confuses VBA local variables with Windows environment variables.  The variables that you are setting in your VBA macro are not visible to the batch file, because the batch file is totally unaware of the VBA environment.

You could fix this (for example by making system calls in the VBA script that set environment variables); however, the bigger problem is that your design makes no sense.
There is no reason to involve VBA and a batch file in the task of running a Perl script, and doing so adds unnecessary complexity.

As others have suggested, why not simply use Perl for the task?

If your Windows users are not comfortable with command line arguments, simply make the script prompt for each file name that is needed.  I would also make your script work with input and output files directly, rather than requiring STDIN and STDOUT to be redirected.  If you do this, then you could create a shortcut for your script and have a very easy way of accessing it.

If some users will want to use the script on the command line, you can accept both modes of input:

```
my $directory;
my $descriptor;
my $input_file;
my $output_file;

#
if (@ARGV == 4)
{
    $directory = $ARGV[0];
    $descriptor = $ARGV[1];
    ...etc.
}
else
{
    print "Enter directory name: "
    $directory = <>;
    chomp $directory;  #remove newline
    ...etc.
}
```

Comment: I was prompting for a name on the command line previously and that was causing some errors, so thought `vba` may help. However, it is a bit more difficult then anticipated.  I will post a new thread in a day or so with a more updated script (maybe it will work).Thank you very much :)